# rails 4 asset_pipeline : Include whole folder for vendor/assets

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

The whole point of this is to include a template from wrap bootstrap. I have been playing around with it, but would it be possible to include a folder to our rails application.css or application.js in app/assets (or even images).

I have put my files from my template under

- vendor/assets/stylesheets/mytemplate/allmycssstuff
- vendor/assets/javascripts/mytemplate/allmyjavascriptsstuff
- vendor/assets/fonts/mytemplate/allmyfontsstuff
- vendor/assets/images/mytemplate/allmyimagesstuff

**For now**, I basically **require each one** and it works, but it's a long process (since sometime templates have plugins). Is it possible to require a folder, so it fetch every file with *.css extension?

So, I would do something like (in app/assets/stylsheets/application.css):

```
*= require mytemplate/*.css (doesn't work)
```

And same for others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `require_tree` directive in the `application.css` and `application.js` manifest files, which will recursively include any files in the given directories.  These are relative paths however, so you'll need something like this:

```
 *= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

Comment: Same principle for the javascripts? What about images and fonts, should they directly be in the app/assets